# Can the AWS lex accept the attachments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

i have developed a AWS lex bot. i want that at the end of a chat session aws lex should give user the ability to attach a .docs or PDF file which later can be stored in the database.
is it possible through JavaScript or lambda function?
if yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lex Chatbot can't accept the image but It's possible by Integrate your Amazon Lex Bot with Amazon API Gateway.

Your application API call to the HTTPS endpoint hosted by AWS API Gateway.
API Gateway deals With Lambda function.
Lambda function runs your business logic and uses the PostText/PostContent to communicate with your Chatbot or call AWS Rekognition service on completion to call your Chatbot using Lambda function.
You will get a response.